# Converting from IEEE floating to binary when the exponent is out of range

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

So I'm trying to convert the following value into binary. The requirement is that it has to have 1 signed bit, 4 exponent bits and 4 frac bits.

This is the value:

`(-1^1) * (1+0) * (2^13)`

So the exponent would be 13 + 7 (e + bias) right? Which would be 20. But I can't represent 20 in 4 bits. What do I do?

Comment: What does IEEE-754 have to do with this?

Comment: You should look up the rules for handling overflow in your floating point system.

Comment: Are you doing this manually, like on paper, as an exercise? Or are you writing a program to do it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm doing this on paper

Comment: If the number is too big to be represented and too big to round down to the largest representable finite number, then the result is infinity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If I remember currently, shouldn't I be rounding it if it goes to infinity?

Comment: The expression `-1^1 * 1+0 * 2^13` is `-1`. Do you mean `(-1)^1 * (1+0) * 2^13`?

Comment: @chtz Yes that's what I meant. I will edit it

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Returning infinity when the number is too big to round down to the largest representable finite number is rounding, as the term is used in floating-point work. What other rounding do you think there is to do? Once we decide to produce infinity as the result, the task is done.

Comment: IEEE 754 round-to-nearest first checks whether the result would round down to the maximum finite even if the exponent were wider. If so, return maximum finite. If not, return infinity.